# Python BeautifulSoup - list index after the table?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

i got the below code from the other thread,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=aapl+Options'
htmltext = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

#Table 8 has the data needed; it is nested under other tables though
# specific reference works as below:
print soup.findAll('table')[8].findAll('tr')[2].findAll('td')[2].contents
```

My question here is why i got the error after i change the `('table')[8]` to `('table')[7]` or others index that lower than 8? How do i know which index i should use? I don't get the concept...

Thanks for the advice...

Update:

I'm trying extract the information from a webpage...
There is few  in a , i just need to extract some data in certain ...
that's why i am figuring out which index i should use in my case...

In fact, there is only one table in my html, so i tried to use findAll('table')[0]..
is it correct?

Comment: Perhaps the other table doesn't have as many rows? Without an error message this isn't very easily answered.

Comment: What other post did you find this code in? It's a very brittle way of locating the 'right' table. What table are you looking for, what data does it hold?

Comment: Was it this post: [Python BeautifulSoup Getting a column from table - IndexError List index out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21494085) perhaps? Note that the answer is already giving a hint as to how to locate the right table more robustly. BeautifulSoup supports CSS selectors, if you actually tell us what table you did want it should be trivial to whip something up.

Comment: Also, do you have to use BeautifulSoup? If you could use `lxml.html` or any other decent HTML parser supporting XPath queries, you could get an XPath expression using the developer console available in most browsers and put it at work.

Comment: Thanks all for the prompt response.
In fact, I'm learning up beautifulsoup now and have a very limited knowledge on this.

I do try to remove the 'tr' and 'td' part. Just remain 
print soup.findAll('table')[8]

Comment: Sorry, the table[8] it is indicate this is the table #8 within the one html page?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: No need for XPath here, CSS Selectors work fine.

Comment: As @MartijnPieters said, you should identify children elements by id or class instead of index. It would be more expressive and resilient too. If you could tell us what you are trying to extract exactly, it would be easier for us to help you.

Comment: I just edited my question. My first time post question in stack flow, I'm sorry if i confusing you all...i will try to be specific and clear in next round!

Comment: @MartijnPieters is certainly right about CSS selectors, still if you intend to do a lot of content extraction from HTML or XML, I recommend learning XPath, being a cleaner and more general way to query documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page has outer tables with the class `yfnc_datamodoutline1`, containing a child table with the actual data. You could use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to list each one and extract data:

```
datatables = soup.select('table.yfnc_datamodoutline1 table')
```

This too returns a list you can index, but the number of results is far more manageable and it is clearer what tables you retrieved here. There are only 2 results here now; pick one (Call or Put options), then parse the rows:

```
for row in datatables[1].find_all('tr'):
    if row.th:
        # header row
    else:
        # data row
```

A quick demo printing out the second table:

```
>>> for row in soup.select('table.yfnc_datamodoutline1 table')[1].find_all('tr'):
...     if row.th:
...         print ' '.join(header.get_text() for header in row.find_all('th'))
...     else:
...         print ' '.join(cell.get_text() for cell in row.find_all('td'))
... 
Strike Symbol Last Chg Bid Ask Vol Open Int
280.00 AAPL140517P00280000 0.05  0.00 N/A 0.12 2 6
290.00 AAPL140517P00290000 0.02  0.00 N/A 0.11 11 11
295.00 AAPL140517P00295000 0.01  0.00 N/A 0.08 3 8
300.00 AAPL140517P00300000 0.05  0.00 N/A 0.09 1 23
305.00 AAPL140517P00305000 0.05  0.00 N/A 0.10 10 20
# ... etc.
```

Comment: I try to use this code,
datatables = soup.select('table.yfnc_datamodoutline1 table')
The print datatables return [] in my program. What does this mean?
In fact, there is only one table in the html page.

Comment: @user3622414: It could mean one of two things: either you loaded a HTML page that has a different structure, or the HTML is (slightly) broken and the parser used didn't manage to make sense of it. BeautifulSoup can pick amongst different parsers, and they each can handle broken HTML differently. If you have `lxml` installed already, it is used as the default parser, but I've seen that `lxml` can fail on certain documents *if an older version of `libxml2` is installed on your system*. Try parsing with `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')` and see if that makes a difference.